# Looking for advice on upgrading

Tags: chain

I have a [Specialized Rockhopper SL](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bikes/archive/2010/rockhoppersl/rockhoppersl). It currently has the Rock Shox Dart 3 front shocks and the Shimano HG-50 chain/crank set. I want to upgrade it cause when I hit that top gear and I'm going all out with more to give, it seems like the bike has no more room for me to give it. I am currently doing things like the local Tour de Cure 100 mile bike rides. But I want to keep the bike and use it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are doing a lot of road riding, I'd consider a road bike instead of upgrading a mtb for road riding.

Comment: This question is kinda vague as it is now. Can you clarify what you want from the bike? More speed? Better hill climbing?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much all you can do to a mountain bike to make it better on road rides is fit slick tires, put the smallest cassette you can find which works for hills, fit a rigid fork if you're not taking it off road or lock out your suspension if you can. You can't put a road crankset (which requires road front derailleur to accomodate the larger chainrings) on most mountain bike frames since they won't have the clearance.

A new set of slick tires and the smallest cassette you can find will likely run you on the order of 100 bucks. A bit more money and you can get a used road bike which will work a lot better for road riding. The smallest cassette probably also won't gain you much either, and if you want to go mountain biking without a second set of wheels (which would almost definitely bring you into used road bike territory in pricing) you'd be swapping your slicks for knobbies which is somewhat annoying.

Comment: I don't have first-hand experience, but I've heard it said that you could also fit aero bars to try and improve your position and get some more speed. But this again feels like square peg/round hole

Comment: Well, the first thing would be getting aero bars to clamp on the bars given that mountain bars are different diameter than road bars (and if you're not using a flat bar, that may introduce additional complications). The second thing is the price - aero bars aren't cheap. Then you have to deal with the fit, which I can't imagine being comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested - a road bike would be a better answer and chaining to slicks will help efficiency.

As far as cadence and getting more top speed / lower cadence, the MTB cluster you have will have a smallest cog of 11 teeth - you cannot go smaller (smaller on back is higher gear).  The only other option you have is to increase the chain ring size. MTB chain rings normally stop at 44.

So what size can you go up to - you probably have a 42 at the moment - a 44 is only 5% larger (pedal 5% slower) but over 100 miles it could make a big difference. The clearance with the frame and the front derailleur might prevent such an increase. Going up a couple of teeth could be anything from straight forward chain-ring replacement to difficult and expensive to  impossible.

If you do go up a size, you will probably need a new chain, and possibly a new front derailleur.

Most people that complain about top end speed and want bigger gears are actually not pedalling fast enough for efficiency - more common on MTB's where the riding position and bike geometry is set up more around agility and control than efficiency. There are a few cyclists who can maintain 90+ cadence in top gear on a MTB over 100miles, but not many.  Unless you are maintaining a cadence over 80, I would recommend not changing the bike at all.